# Rails 4 - Controller Edit Action Returning Wrong Record

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Comment model which belongs to both User and Story. Creating a comment correctly associated to the appropriate User and Story is working fine but when trying to edit the comment my edit action appears to retrieving the wrong record.

The offending action in comments_controller.rb:

```
def edit
  @story = Story.find_by(params[:story_id])
  @comment = @story.comments.find_by(params[:id])
end
```

The link used to render the comments/edit view:

```
<%= link_to 'edit', edit_story_comment_path(comment.story_id, comment.id) %>
```

The corresponding view:

```
<%= form_for(@comment, url: { controller: 'comments', action: 'update' }) do |f| %> 
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
  <%= f.submit "update" %>
<% end %>
```

The edit view appears to be rendering the most recently added comment regardless of which @comment I am trying to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `find_by`, which is basically a magic `find_by_X` method, with no fields specified. `find_by(1)` generates invalid SQL for me using Postgres, but it might be that whatever database back-end your using accepts it.

Regardless, `find_by` certainly won't do what you want it to do.

You should be using `find`, if you want to find records by `id`:

```
@story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
```